# what is model based search?

Tags: django, solr, search-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

When I reading `haystack` document, I got `Haystack is very Model-based and doesn’t work well outside of that use case.`. What is model based search and model based data. Does google or bing search engine make model search? Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/

> A model is the single, definitive source of data about your data. It
>   contains the essential fields and behaviors of the data you’re
>   storing. Generally, each model maps to a single database table.

Basically a model is a class that contains data and methods that relate to certain data from a data source i.e. a database table.

> Does google or bing search engine make model search?

No. Not that I'm aware of. Google uses it's own index of your site and doesn't offer a way of using data from your database.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/api

The same goes for Bing. These are different from Solr or ElasticSearch which get implemented on your server and can access data in your database through an API. Whereas Google and Bing have APIs which simply allow you to use their search engine's cache of your website.

Comment: Does that mean haystack+solr or haystack+elasticsearch only suitable for searching in my own website like a blog?@user972481

Comment: Correct. If you plan on using Haystack. You could use Google custom search, but it has some limits. Google doesn't allow full customizing of the page layout. Google will allow you to upload a logo and customize the colors but that's about it. With Haystack you basically have full control over what gets searched and how it gets displayed. Google also limits you to 20,000 searches a year, after that it you have to pay money.

Comment: Actually, I want create a search engine like google. I crawl data using Ntuch, I want to build indexes from those data, and I dont want store them to mysql. So that's no model here. Should I stop trying to use haystack?

Comment: Basically Google is easier to setup but has limitations. Haystack is more advanced but allows you to have full control over your search.  If you have a small website with minimal traffic Google is probably an easy place to start. You could probably setup Google custom search within 15 minutes. But if you have lot's of traffic, need more control over the search parameters, or want to fully integrate your site's design with the search results than Haystack would be better.

Comment: After reading it looks like you don't need a DBMS after all. The queries can all be handled by Solr. And in the Haystack docs it also states... SearchIndex objects are the way Haystack determines what data should be placed in the search index and handles the flow of data in. You can think of them as being similar to Django Models or Forms in that they are field-based and manipulate/store data.

Comment: But I would definitely stick to the Django/Haystack/Solr platform as it seems like it might be easy to implement. I just have to read more as some of this is new to me. I'll see if I can get some of this stuff working on my own tomorrow and let you know what I learn.

Comment: Thanks for ur time @user972481 . Nutch can crawl webpage, and then build index via elasticsearch or solr, now I just need a UI to retrieve everything. So why you need an extra step, which is storing data to database?